# Why mycourses[i].getGrade() doesn't return anything (C++)?

Tags: c++, function, header, return-value, program-entry-point

I am having problem with the getGrade() function in header file not returning letter grade based on marks entered by the user in the main file. When I compile and run the program doesn't display the letter grade according to the marks entered.

Header file (course.h)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Course {
private:
    int totalMarks;
    char grade;


public:
    void marksInfo(int tm)
    {
        totalMarks = tm;
    }

    int getMarks(void)
    {
        return totalMarks;
    }

    void setGrade(char c)
    {
        if(totalMarks <= 39)
            c = 'E';

        if(totalMarks >= 40 && totalMarks <= 49)
            c = 'D';

        if(totalMarks >= 50 && totalMarks <= 64)
            c = 'C'
    }

    char getGrade(void)
    {
        return grade;
    }
 };
```

Main file

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include "course.h"

 using namespace std;

 int main()
   {
      int tm;

      Course course[5];

      for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      {
          cout << "Subject #" << i+1 << endl;

          cout << "Total Marks #" << i+1 << ": ";
          cin >> tm;

          course[i].marksInfo(tm);

          cout << endl;

          course[i].getGrade();
      }

      cout << "Grade: " << course[0].getGrade();
  }
```

Comment: You don't call 'setGrade' so why would it?

Comment: You have to use `setGrade` before you can `getGrade`.

Comment: Thank you both... now it displays the letter grade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code never sets `grade` *to* anything. You also have a problem-in-waiting:

```
void setGrade(char c)
{
    if(totalMarks <= 39)
        c = 'E';

    if(totalMarks >= 40 && totalMarks <= 49)
        c = 'D';

    if(totalMarks >= 50 && totalMarks <= 64)
        c = 'C'
}
```

this function never changes `grade`, what it does is it populates a *local variable* called 'C' with a value based on totalMarks and then immediately forgets it. I think what you wanted was more something like this:

```
class Course {
private:
    int totalMarks;
    char grade;


public:
    void marksInfo(int tm)
    {
        totalMarks = tm;

        if(totalMarks <= 39)
            grade = 'E';
        else if(totalMarks >= 40 && totalMarks <= 49)
            grade = 'D';
        else if(totalMarks >= 50 && totalMarks <= 64)
            grade = 'C';
        else if(totalMarks >= 65 && totalMarks <= 84)
            grade = 'B';
        else
            grade = 'A';
    }

    int getMarks(void)
    {
        return totalMarks;
    }

    char getGrade(void)
    {
        return grade;
    }
 };
```